# Android: Text does not appear in custom dropdown spinner but its respective icon does appear

Tags: java, android

I have been following this tutorial of a dropdown [this](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html) tutorial to add a custom dropdown spinner in my app. The change I made is just I added have an array of numbers instead of an array of strings. But the number isn't appearing on the spinner, just the icon alongside the number is appearing. Furthermore, the spinner has enlarged in size and I can't figure out why.

Here's what is being displayed on the app(I have customized the spinner only for the "Light Intensity"):

[image]

Posted below are code snippets from the relevant files.

AlertsFragment.java

```
public class AlertsFragment extends Fragment{

    private Switch switchBadge;
    int [] numbers={10,20,30,40,50,60,70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120};
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.low, R.drawable.low, R.drawable.low, R.drawable.low,
            R.drawable.medium, R.drawable.medium, R.drawable.medium, R.drawable.medium,
            R.drawable.high, R.drawable.high, R.drawable.high, R.drawable.high};


    private AlertsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;

  //omitted some fragment functions codes

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alerts, container, false);

        switchBadge= (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.BadgeSwitch);
        switchBadge.setChecked(false);
        switchBadge.setTextOn("On");
        switchBadge.setTextOff("Off");

        Spinner spin = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.LDRspinner);
        //spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),flags,numbers);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        return view;
    }
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int level[];
    int[] numbers;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] level, int[] numbers) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.level = level;
        this.numbers = numbers;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return level.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(level[i]);
        names.setText(String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
        return view;
    }

}
```

custom_spinner_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/high" /><!--Make sure image is present in Drawable folder-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

part of fragment_alerts.xml:

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/LDRspinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

There is one more spinner for "Humidity" on the app below "Temperature" but since I customized the Light Intensity spinner, it is no longer showing.

I would appreciate some help in fixing all this.

Comment: Change the `layout_height` on the item's `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content`. That should take care of the vertical enlarging. Then try removing the `padding` on the `TextView`. That `activity_horizontal_margin` is likely bigger than expected. If that doesn't fix the text, set a background color on the `TextView`, and see what it looks like.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much! That worked! Thanks a lot for your prompt reply as always, you've been helping me a great deal in my final year project :)